# Npx create-react-native-app cannot find module '@npmcli/config'

Tags: react-native

I can't use the command `npx create-react-native-app` in VS Code. I'm getting these errors when I'm running the command:

```js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1073
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@npmcli/config'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/definition.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/definitions.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/flatten.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/index.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1070:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:923:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/definition.js:33:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/definition.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/definitions.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/flatten.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/config/index.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npx-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

As recommended below, running `npm list -g --depth 0` would also produce the following error:

```js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1070
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/cli.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1070:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:923:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/cli.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

My Node.js is the latest - v20.3.0. Not sure if my nodejs is in the wrong path. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please provide list of your global packages `npm list -g --depth 0`

Comment: I did that and it says: 

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1070
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/cli.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js 
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/cli.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

Comment: So you have some error in nodejs, I recommend installing some package manager, for example, https://github.com/Schniz/fnm Also you can try using node v18 instead v20 (with fnm it is elementary to change nodejs version). Good luck!